# Arrange a matrix into unique rows and columns

Tags: r, matrix, combinatorics

Say I have a vector,

```
vec <- c(rep(1,4),rep(2,4),rep(3,4),rep(4,4),rep(5,4),rep(6,4),rep(7,4),rep(8,4),rep(9,4))
```

that I arranged into a matrix 6x6.

```
mat <- matrix(vec,6,byrow=T)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    2    2
[2,]    2    2    3    3    3    3
[3,]    4    4    4    4    5    5
[4,]    5    5    6    6    6    6
[5,]    7    7    7    7    8    8
[6,]    8    8    9    9    9    9
```

I would like to have the numbers shuffled around such that they are unique for each row and column. Or in other words, there must be no duplicates numbers in any row or column.

The length of the vector, the elements of the vector, the number of rows and columns of the matrix are all fixed. The only aspect that can be changed is the placement of the numbers.

How would I go about solving this computationally?

Below is one possible correct result (done manually). Note that no row or column has any duplicate number.

```
res <- matrix(c(3,1,2,5,7,8,6,8,5,2,9,4,8,6,7,4,3,5,2,9,3,1,6,7,1,4,9,7,5,6,4,2,1,9,8,3),nrow=6,byrow=T)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    3    1    2    5    7    8
[2,]    6    8    5    2    9    4
[3,]    8    6    7    4    3    5
[4,]    2    9    3    1    6    7
[5,]    1    4    9    7    5    6
[6,]    4    2    1    9    8    3

table(res)

res
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

Comment: This is really more of an R coding question than a question about statistics. It is off topic here, but should be on topic on [SO]. If you wait a bit, we can migrate it for you.

Comment: Interesting. I posted this on SO. It was downvoted a lot saying the question was not clear, not a programming question etc and unsuitable for SO. So I posted it on CrossValidated, and now it has been migrated to SO again.

Comment: There are some odd quirks in people's opinions. 'How to get R to give permutations', & 'how to rearrange a matrix', are clearly coding questions, & not at all about statistics, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

To start, there is a better way to get your vector.  This will entail less typing and make your code clearer:

```
vec <- rep(1:8, each=4)
mat <- matrix(vec, ncol=6, byrow=T)
```

Next, note that you are asking for unique orderings of the elements by rows.  That is, you want the [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of your elements.  The number of unique permutations of `N` elements is `N!`.  We can compute that number in `R` thus:

```
factorial(length(unique(vec)))
# [1] 40320
```

That is way more orderings of your numbers than you need.  (it seems you just want 6.)  Assuming you would like to draw some random orderings, lets draw 6 numbers from the possible 40320:

```
set.seed(3931)  # this makes the example exactly reproducible
rows <- sample.int(40320, 6)
rows
# [1] 36601 24136  5713 23405 25328 32973
```

From here, to get the actual permutations, we will use the [permute](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/permute/index.html) library in `R`.  Because the total number of permutations is large, we will have to set the `maxperm` argument to be larger than its default (`9999`, I gather):

```
library(permute)
out <- allPerms(unique(vec), control=how(maxperm=41000))[rows,]
out
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
# [1,]    8    2    7    1    3    4    6    5
# [2,]    5    7    4    1    6    8    2    3
# [3,]    2    1    8    6    3    4    7    5
# [4,]    5    6    4    1    2    8    7    3
# [5,]    6    1    3    2    5    7    4    8
# [6,]    7    4    6    5    8    2    3    1
```

---

My apologies for misreading the question.  The number of permutations of `N` elements, when you will only use `r` of them is `N!/r!`.  Here is a simple calculation:

```
factorial(length(unique(vec))) / factorial(length(unique(vec))-6)
# [1] 20160
```

It isn't clear to me how to get `allPerms()` to use fewer than all elements.  Here is a simple kludge to get around that:

```
library(permute)
out <- allPerms(unique(vec), control=how(maxperm=41000))[rows,1:6]
out
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    8    2    7    1    3    4
# [2,]    5    7    4    1    6    8
# [3,]    2    1    8    6    3    4
# [4,]    5    6    4    1    2    8
# [5,]    6    1    3    2    5    7
# [6,]    7    4    6    5    8    2
```

Comment: This is impressive. But, the `out` is a 8x6 matrix while it should be a 6x6 matrix. Also `table(as.vector(out))` returns 1:9 6 each. It must be 1:9 4 each. Anyhow this is a good place for me to start fiddling. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hmmm, good point, I didn't look closely enough. I'll take another look when I get a chance. I'm pretty busy right now.